# All Gravitars Failing on Domain 2, work on Domain 1 - WordPress Profile Photos

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain, gravatar

All user profile pictures are failing since I changed the domain name for the site. They also fail to work in "Settings, Discussion, Default Avatar" list. This is the only issues I have found so far...

[image]

The WordPress site is physically the same, I just have an old and a new DNS name.  If I temporarily change back to using the old domain the avatars work again.

Google Chrome Dev Tools shows "**ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT**", I type the URL into chrome, I get the correct gravatar.  What is the client, my browser or the WP server?  I have disabled AVG on my windows computer without any improvement, and I have disabled all plugins in WP again no improvements.

As far as I can tell there is no server or browser caching issues involved.

**Dev Tools shows**:
Request URL: https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/caa7f7ac741d667181928dddf7cf2f69?s=32&f=y&r=pg
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

No Response Headers

If I type "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/caa7f7ac741d667181928dddf7cf2f69?s=32&f=y&r=pg" into my browser it correct displays the profile image.

This is the html code for one of those images:
`<label> <input type="radio" name="avatar_default" id="avatar_gravatar_default" value="gravatar_default">  <img alt="" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/caa7f7ac741d667181928dddf7cf2f69?s=32&amp;f=y&amp;r=pg"  srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/caa7f7ac741d667181928dddf7cf2f69?s=64&amp;f=y&amp;r=pg 2x"  class="avatar avatar-32 photo avatar-default" height="32" width="32" loading="lazy" decoding="async"> Gravatar Logo </label>`

Comment: I just saved the "settings, Discussion" page as a local HTML page, when I display that, all the images show,..  Then again, it works the first time the page is loaded and fails on F5 (refresh).

Answer (score 0):

It was a privacy related Chrome extension (Ghostery):

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ghostery-%E2%80%93-privacy-ad-blo/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij

I normally would have picked up the problem but this time didn't, the new domain didn't have any exceptions,  Anyway, so the client really was my computer and I hope this helps someone who has the same issue downstream :-)